# How can I take an in-game screenshot of any game?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

How do you do this? Sometimes I'll be playing a game and find something funny I'd like to save as a picture, but there seems to be no option to do this.

I remember Nintendo updating the 3DS and saying we could screenshot the game, but I can't find anything that would work.  I've tried using Game Notes and using Home >> Camera, but that doesn't do the trick either.

Comment: @DavidM Now it references the 3DSXL, which is completely different in terms of hardware

Comment: Ah.  Gotcha.  Sorry, I don't have an answer, though.

Comment: How it works should be the same, though. Nintendo rarely changes stuff like that.

Comment: I don't see how it's different; the button layout is different, but it's the exact same hardware, with slightly larger screens.

Comment: If you press L and R together in Animal Crossing it takes pictures but I am not sure if that works everywhere.